# Getting NULL values for a multiple column IF statement passed to MAPPLY

Tags: r, if-statement, mapply

I have a data frame of data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(11, 3, 2, 7, 9, 4, 6, 1, 6, 7),
                 y = c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5)))

df
    x y
1  11 a
2   3 a
3   2 a
4   7 a
5   9 a
6   4 b
7   6 b
8   1 b
9   6 b
10  7 b
```

What I'm trying to do is an IF statement on both columns x and y, where it assigns a new value (z) based on meeting the criteria of x and y.

```
myfun <- function(x,y) {
  if(x < 3 & y=="a") z <- 1
  if(x>=3 & x <=7 & y=="a") z <- 2
  if(x>7 & y=="a") z <- 3
  if(x<3 & y=="b") z <-4
  if(x>=3 & x<=1 & y=="b") z <-5
  if(x>7 & y=="b") z<-6
}
```

I am trying to get the following result based on that logic above:

```
df
    x y z
1  11 a 3
2   3 a 2
3   2 a 1
4   7 a 2
5   9 a 3 
6   4 b 5
7   6 b 5
8   1 b 4
9   6 b 5
10  7 b 5

df$z <- mapply(myfun, df$x, df$x)
```

This results in:

```
x y    z
1  11 a NULL
2   3 a NULL
3   2 a NULL
4   7 a NULL
5   9 a NULL
6   4 b NULL
7   6 b NULL
8   1 b NULL
9   6 b NULL
10  7 b NULL
```

I have no idea why. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if() function is not supposed to be used for vectors (or columns). It is used for single object comparisons like if(switch=="on"). What you should use is the ifelse() function. Your first three conditions would become:

```
myfun <- function(df) {
  df$z <- with(df, ifelse(x < 3 & y=="a",1,NA))
  df$z <- with(df, ifelse(x>=3 & x <=7 & y=="a",2,df$z))
  df$z <- with(df, ifelse(x>7 & y=="a",3,df$z))
  ...
}
```

edit: and using df$x and df$y in the function call is probably not necessary. "result <- myfun(df)" would be enough unless you want x and y to be different.